# Sortable table empty when using data from REST API instead of from JSON file

Tags: reactjs, json, rest, axios

I'm building my first React project, and have started by making a sortable table. For the content, I made a local JSON file and filled it with data, used some online tutorials to build the table element and implement the sorting. All seems good so far.

Next I wanted to switch to getting the table content from a REST API rather than a local file. I can retrieve the data without any issues, and if I disable the sorting the table content renders fine. However, if I try and use the sorting logic, I end up with no data in the table at all.

My App is very simple:

i

```
mport HardwaresTable from "./tc/HardwaresTable";

const App = () => {

    return (
        <div className="table_container">
            <HardwaresTable/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

The HardwaresTable component defines the columns and retrieves the data:

```
import Table from "../components/Table";
import testHardwares from "../test/hardwares.json";
import TableHead from "../components/TableHead";
import TableBody from "../components/TableBody";
import {useSortableTable} from "../util/useSortableTable";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const HardwaresTable = () => {
    const hardwaresColumns = [
        { label: "ID", accessor: "id", sortable: true, sortByOrder: "asc", type: "int" },
        { label: "Hardware Name", accessor: "hardwareName", sortable: false, type: "string" },
        { label: "Display Name", accessor: "displayName", sortable: true, type: "string" },
        { label: "Hardware Make", accessor: "hardwareMake", sortable: true, type: "enum" },
        { label: "Hardware Type", accessor: "hardwareType", sortable: true, type: "enum" },
        { label: "Multiplier", accessor: "multiplier", sortable: true, type: "double" },
        { label: "Average PPD", accessor: "averagePpd", sortable: true, type: "int" },
    ];

    const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);
    const [hardwares:[], setHardwares] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData() {
            await axios
                .get("https://internal.axihub.ca/folding/hardware")
                .then((response) => {
                    // console.log(response.data);
                    setHardwares(response.data);
                });
        }
        if (loadingData) {
            getData()
                .then(r => {
                    setLoadingData(false)
                });
        }
    }, []);

    //// 'hardwares' has all content correctly here ////
    const [tableData, handleSorting] = useSortableTable(hardwares, hardwaresColumns);
    //// After calling 'useSortableTable()', 'tableData' is empty ////

    return (
        <table className="table">
            <caption>Hardwares on the system</caption>
            <TableHead columns={hardwaresColumns} handleSorting={handleSorting} />
            {loadingData ? "" : <TableBody tableData={tableData} columns={hardwaresColumns} />}
        </table>
    );
};

export default HardwaresTable;
```

And the useSortableTable logic is what seems to cause the problems;. If I don't use this logic (and simply pass the data from the REST response directly into the TableBody component), the data does load fine:

```
import {useState} from "react";

function getDefaultSorting(defaultTableData: any[], columns: any) {
    return [...defaultTableData].sort((a, b) => {
        const filterColumn = columns.filter((column: { sortByOrder: boolean; }) => column.sortByOrder);

        // Merge all array objects into single object and extract accessor and sortByOrder keys
        let {accessor = "id", sortByOrder = "asc"} = Object.assign(
            {},
            ...filterColumn
        );

        if (a[accessor] === null) return 1;
        if (b[accessor] === null) return -1;
        if (a[accessor] === null && b[accessor] === null) return 0;

        const ascending = a[accessor]
            .toString()
            .localeCompare(b[accessor].toString(), "en", {
                numeric: true,
            });

        return sortByOrder === "asc" ? ascending : -ascending;
    });
}

export const useSortableTable = (data: any, columns: any) => {
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(getDefaultSorting(data, columns));
    console.log(tableData);

    const handleSorting = (sortField: any, sortOrder: string) => {
        if (sortField) {
            const sorted = [...tableData].sort((a, b) => {
                if (a[sortField] === null) return 1;
                if (b[sortField] === null) return -1;
                if (a[sortField] === null && b[sortField] === null) return 0;
                return (
                    a[sortField]
                        .toString()
                        .localeCompare(b[sortField].toString(), "en", {
                            numeric: true,
                        }) * (sortOrder === "asc" ? 1 : -1)
                );
            });
            setTableData(sorted);
        }
    };

    return [tableData, handleSorting];
};
```

I'm assuming there is some issue with the types of the data that is causing no elements to be sorted (and an empty array being returned), but I'm not familiar enough with React to know how to figure that out. Would appreciate some pointers on where to look and how to confirm (if it is indeed typing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the state update of the tableData. You are initializing it with hardware when it is empty and expecting tableData to pick it up once hardware state is updated. But react doesn't change the hook initialization, the only way to update the underlying state is to use the state updating function(setState).

To fix your problem, I exposed the set function as well from the sorting hook. I also removed the extra state.

Please have a look at this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/singh44ashutosh/table-sorting/master?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm0s515k000j356cii1r1424%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm0s515k000e356ckcqyh7sm%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm0s515k000i356c5f9cvktp%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm0s515k000g356clrvgn3yk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B38.23529411764706%252C61.76470588235294%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clm0s515k000e356ckcqyh7sm%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm0s515j000d356c8fhitxng%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm0s515k000e356ckcqyh7sm%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clm0s515j000d356c8fhitxng%2522%257D%252C%2522clm0s515k000g356clrvgn3yk%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm0s515k000g356clrvgn3yk%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clm0s5ox100xo356c8o3bakn3%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm0s5ox100xo356c8o3bakn3%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clm0s515k000i356c5f9cvktp%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm0s515k000i356c5f9cvktp%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clm0s5l6300mr356ctqx9wu8e%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm0s515k000h356cm28cgmoa%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clm0s53b0000xe6il3tn8bwzs%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm0s5l6300mr356ctqx9wu8e%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

I have used my own TableHeader and TableBody components as you had not given that. Styling is left to you.

I have also added one component TestStatePass as POC.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did run into a couple problems, but was able to figure out what I was doing wrong. Appreciate you putting it together in a sandbox, was able to work with that quite well. :)